# How to run a Power Automate flow on a selected folder in a library

Tags: power-automate

I searched this topic but only found a few old posts from 2019 that no longer apply.
The Power Automate Action command now shows up with a folder selected.

I want to run a flow on the selected folder, but not when a document is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I did some experimenting and found how to run a flow on a selected folder in a SharePoint library.

You start with the trigger "for a selected file" and then inspect the itemURL, which will have a different format for a document versus a folder. You can then terminate the workflow if the selected item is a document and continue with the processing if it's a folder.

I've written it up with screenshots and lots of detail in this blog post: https://teylyn.com/2023/12/07/run-power-automate-for-a-selected-folder-in-sharepoint/

Let me know if you find this useful.

Comment: Great article  Too bad there is no `for a folder selected` trigger and this kind of trigger can only reside in the default environment.